# Deploying HaxeFlixel game to Android device

Tags: android, virtualbox, haxe, haxeflixel, lime-haxe

I'm making a game for android with HaxeFlixel. I'm using VirtualBox to run Windows 7 on my Mac. After developing and building a game in FlashDevelop, I've navigated to the project folder in the command prompt and run this command:

```
lime test android
```

I get:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL:
error: device not found
error: device not found
-waiting for device
```

I made sure VirtualBox is recognizing my Android device in file explorer and in the devices tab in the context menu. I also ran `lime setup` and made sure I have all the Android development packages and the same version as my phone.

Any idea why my device isn't found?
Is there another way to deploy my HaxeFlixel project to my Android device?

Comment: Maybe you need to install Universal Android ADB Driver: http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Comment: I will try this. Thank you

Comment: Yep, this was it. Thanks!

Comment: I just add the answer. Accept it so anyone else with the same problem can see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Universal Android ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) will solve the problem.